# send string from c# windows form application to asp.net web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

i have a table in ms-access database

i create DataTable using select query

then convert DataTable to json and then i compress json because raw json size is 13mb

now i want to send this compressed json  to webserver

windows from application side

```
public string webPostMethod() {

  string URL = "https://mywebsite.com/Default.aspx/SendSaleJson";

  var theWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
  theWebRequest.Method = "POST";
  theWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  theWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");

  using(var writer = theWebRequest.GetRequestStream()) {

    // i want to send this string ZipJson to webserver
    string ZipJson = "cAMAAB+LCAAAAAAABACdkV9LwzAUxb9K6fM2mtQg7VuWpBrWJTWJaBEpZRsIOhlu+iJ+d2/6b26ojJW+nHPvPfe2v4fPUBsuTKV0mIYoHHWSUyfAiNCYbt7GGAcIp1EEb0DnQ5OTc9+EUBqRlFy0JXstM1e5svAlu3pZLXbgOjrNxX7JHZXOL6VNABhKVzqrCmGsVq1TGM0rpnmzgfQGF5aBwXTOA6azTAio3Liyy7UUtpj2dhTHkzgGk4G+0qZs5vxIYAVzEhb5u+79ZVAqQdG5vlVumI32jw8Xyply/w2FkcoJ3o1OZZ43QvVnDI2L9+2ueq3XK9BJl4ov+0K9XDb/cOjcPIHe1uuP+rmP+pfG1+iAIT6XIQGMyYkM8RkMUXIEUQdGMhEwQ9lMmIEjOeaYTCJyiHFqBJ1l1Lq/CSZkgskhNHwqNHwE7Qec32m1+gRUj98dKmcYcAMAAA==";
    string send = null;
    send = "{\"value\":\"test\"}";

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send);

    writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }

  var theWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) theWebRequest.GetResponse();
  var theResponseStream = new StreamReader(theWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

  string result = theResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
  return result;

}
```

asp.net server side

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static string Senddata(string value)
    {
        return "data Received: " + value;
    }
```

This code is working fine but i can't send `ZipJson` string to server.

Comment: You have stated a lot of stuff, and you said your code is working, but it's not. That's confusing. What are you asking us?

Comment: // i want to send this string ZipJson to webserver   
    string ZipJson = "cAMAAB+LCAAAAAAABACdkV9LwzAUxb9K6fM2mtQg7VuWpBrWJTWJaBEpZRsIOhlu+iJ+d2/6b26ojJW+nHPvPfe2v4fPUBsuTKV0mIYoHHWSUyfAiNCYbt7GGAcIp1EEb0DnQ5OTc9+EUBqRlFy0JXstM1e5svAlu3pZLXbgOjrNxX7JHZXOL6VNABhKVzqrCmGsVq1TGM0rpnmzgfQGF5aBwXTOA6azTAio3Liyy7UUtpj2dhTHkzgGk4G+0qZs5vxIYAVzEhb5u+79ZVAqQdG5vlVumI32jw8Xyply/w2FkcoJ3o1OZZ43QvVnDI2L9+2ueq3XK9BJl4ov+0K9XDb/cOjcPIHe1uuP+rmP+pfG1+iAIT6XIQGMyYkM8RkMUXIEUQdGMhEwQ9lMmIEjOeaYTCJyiHFqBJ1l1Lq/CSZkgskhNHwqNHwE7Qec32m1+gRUj98dKmcYcAMAAA==";

Comment: Use an http client to send a post request to your web API, where the content of the request is equal to the string you want to send.

Comment: @VivekNandan - You are still stating something. What are you asking?

Comment: sir i solve this problem using other approach
save compress json in a txt file 
then upload this txt file to server
then read uploaded txt file from server folder 
then insert into database
successfully

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` instead of  `"application/json; charset=utf-8";`

Or use your zip data as json string like this:

send = "{"value":"test", "zipdata" : "YOUR STRING"}";

Answer (score -1):

You only declare the 'ZipJson' string but didn't use or send it. You have to pass that string to the web server.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what the OP wants, but you're just restating the want and not giving an answer.

Comment: Still learning.. You should post the write answer! That way we can learn right?